# Direction of the main beam of an antenna

Tags: antenna, radiation

How can I find direction of the main beam of an antenna if antenna has radiation intensity as following?

$$U=[\dfrac{sin(5\pi cos\theta)}{10sin(\pi cos(\theta/2))}]^2$$
Where
$$0<\theta<\pi$$

My first trial is to find the places where derivatives equal to zero. But the results also give places of the nulls. So, how should I distinguish themain beam between the all nulls (zeros) and sidelobe peaks (local maximas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But the results also give places of the nulls. So, how should I
> distinguish themain beam between the all nulls (zeros) and sidelobe
> peaks (local maximas)?*

Use your favourite spreadsheet and produce a graph then you get all your information together. The formula is not hard to use in (say) excel.

Answer (score 0):

By evaluating U at the local extrema you found, as well as the endpoints of the domain, and picking the one with the highest value. No fancy tricks.